# What is the difference between the python version stated in conda info and that given in conda list?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment

I created a python environment with the command 
"conda create py2.7 python=2.7.16" and conda list shows that indeed, the python package installed in this environment is 2.7.16. (1)

However, when I activate this environment and look at the python version, it is 3.7.3.final.0. (Image 2) Does this mean that I did not create my environment properly? If I did, what information does python version give in conda info?

(1)

```
conda list
Name:   Version:   Build:
...     ...        ...
python  2.7.16     hccbe200_0
```

(2)

```
conda info
active environment : py2.7 
...
python version:3.7.3.final.0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Conda includes a `conda` Python package and this is installed in the **base** env. When `conda info` is called, the Python version that is reported is the version that the Conda package is executing under, e.g., `sys.version_info` (see [package code](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/f32904bef0606fab12ee9d87380ca4201c5c4996/conda/cli/main_info.py#L176)). Hence, it will always report the **base** env's Python, no matter what env is activated.

If you want to know the Python version of an activated env, then use `python --version` or `conda list '^python$'`.