# Conda env: confusing python versions in conda info and actual python command

Tags: python, conda, miniconda

I created a new conda env with python 3.11 and here is the conda env info:

```
rakesh@Rakeshs-MBP ~ % conda activate mlearn                      
(mlearn) rakesh@Rakeshs-MBP ~ % conda info

     active environment : mlearn
    active env location : /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mlearn
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/rks/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/rks/.condarc
          conda version : 23.9.0
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.11.4.final.0
       virtual packages : __archspec=1=x86_64
                          __osx=14.0=0
                          __unix=0=0
       base environment : /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/pkgs
                          /Users/rks/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs
                          /Users/rks/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/23.9.0 requests/2.31.0 CPython/3.11.4 Darwin/23.0.0 OSX/14.0
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

According to this the python version should be 3.11.4. But the python version for python on command line is 3.11.5:

```
(mlearn) rks@Rks-MBP ~ % which python
/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/envs/mlearn/bin/python
(mlearn) rks@Rks-MBP ~ % python --version
Python 3.11.5
```

Is this how it should be or am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between the python version stated in conda info and that given in conda list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56848462/what-is-the-difference-between-the-python-version-stated-in-conda-info-and-that)

Comment: Specifically, from the accepted answer to the duplicate question: *"When conda info is called, the Python version that is reported is the version that the Conda package is executing under, e.g., sys.version_info (see package code). Hence, it will always report the base env's Python, no matter what env is activated."*